# Widget showing products on Homepage, can't find phtml file of it (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, widget

I have a widget added in CMS to show product items of a category on my homepage. I need to make changes in the code around the items. Unfortunately path hints doesn't show me which phtml file it is.

I made changes in the following files without success:

```
Magento_Catalog > templates > product > widgets > (tried all files)

Magento_Catalog_Widget > templates > product > widget > content > grid.phtml
```

But no change to the output.

Comment: which widget exactly are you using?

Comment: I use the WYSIWYG editor to put it in: Insert Widget > Catalog Product List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake, correct it must be **Magento_CatalogWidget** and not **Magento_Catalog_Widget**.

Correct path:

```
Magento_CatalogWidget > templates > product > widget > content > grid.phtml
```